# Regex replace hashtags with links

Tags: javascript

I checked other topics but couldn't find a clear answer to my question.
I am making a hashtag system but with javascript
so i made my regex and tested it, it is right so now i am trying to replace the hashtag words with links so i need your help please how to place the matched words with # in link and without # in the link href

```
      var regex1 = /#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/ig;
      var strin = "hello this is a test. #hello #hashtags #one #two";
                    var result1 = strin.match(regex1);

                    if(result1 !== null) {


                        strin = strin.replace(regex1,"<a href='search.php?sec=all&q="+wordsHere+"' class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>"+hashtagWordHere+"</a>");

                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace second parameter can be a function where its first param is the value matched, so using this value, you can build your string. something like that.

```js
const regex = /#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/ig;
const text = "hello this is a test. #hello #hashtags #one #two";
const replaced = text.replace(regex, value => `<a href='search.php?sec=all&q=${value.substring(1)}' class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>${value}</a>`);

console.log(replaced);
```

```js
const regex = /#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/ig;
const text = "hello this is a test. #hello #hashtags #one #two";
const replaced = text.replace(regex, function(value) {
  return (
    "<a href='search.php?sec=all&q="+value.substring(1)+"' class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>"+value+"</a>"
  )
});

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: naortor thanks a lot it worked ! but can you please explain (value) where did it come from and what does it mean ?

Comment: np, the String.replace function takes a callback as second argument, this cb is being called anytime the replace function finds a match, with the matched value as parameter. the replace function will replace the matched value with the returned value coming back from the callback.

Comment: naortor i think you are using the new javascript syntax which i am not familiar with, so you mean the (value) => is a function ?

Comment: @jwright91 yes, I wrote another version using older syntax.